# Limits and Convergence

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Prove: If $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1}-a_n = 0$ then $a_n$ has to converge.

I understand that the distance between adjacent $a_n$ elements approaches $0$. Since $a_{n+1}-a_n$ converges it has a monotonous subsequence in which all consecutive $a_{n+1}-a_n$ are smaller (or equal) to previous. Could I use that to prove that $a_n$ is a Cauchy series and therefore converges?

I'm not sure if that's in the right direction.
Could someone please help me understand this?

Comment: Isn't it wrong? Consider $a_n := \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$. It holds: $a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac{1}{1+n} \to 0$. But $a_n$ itself diverges to $+\infty$. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is probably very obvious but how do you prove $a_n$ diverges to infinity?

Comment: This didn't fit into comment... See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is wrong.

Consider the partial sums of the [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29) as counter-example:

$\qquad a_n := \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$

Obviously, the difference between $a_{n+1}$ and $a_n$ tends to zero:

$\qquad \lim_{n\to\infty} (a_{n+1} - a_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+n}  = 0$,

However, it holds:

$\qquad a_{2^{N+1}} - a_{2^N} = \sum_{k = 2^N+1}^{2^{N+1}} \frac{1}{k} \geq \sum_{k=2^N+1}^{2^{N+1}} \frac{1}{2^{N+1}} = \frac{2^N}{2^{N+1}} = \frac{1}{2}$,

therefore, by induction we get: $a_{2^N} > \frac{N}{2} \to \infty$ for $N\to\infty$, so that the sequence $(a_n)_n$ contains a divergent subsequence, and is therefore itself divergent.

This is somewhat more intuitive if written out by grouping blocks of size $2^N$:

$\qquad \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} = 1 + (\frac{1}{2}) + (\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4}) + (\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{8}) + \dots \\ \qquad \qquad \quad \geq 0 + (\frac{1}{2}) + (\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}) + (\frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8}) + \dots \\ \qquad \qquad \quad \geq \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \dots$

Comment: Thanks a lot this is much clearer now.
But shouldn't it be:

$\qquad a_{2^{N+1}} - a_{2^N} = \sum_{k = 2^N+1}^{2^{N+1}} \frac{1}{k}$.
Since $\frac{1}{2^N}$  was subtracted (e.g. $2^3-2^2$ would leave $5...8$).

Comment: Yeah, you are right... Some indices are wrong. But I hope it's still useful at least as a proof-sketch, it points in roughly the right direction. You can actually group the sequence slightly differently, so that blocks sum up to 1 for example, maybe it looks more aesthetic with 1 than $1/2$.